# Access a json values by their key

Tags: haskell, aeson

I want to get a value from a json object using a key

```hs
      let nm = case rep_json of
            Object v -> case HM.lookup "names" v of
              Just endps -> Just v
              _ -> Nothing
            _ -> Nothing
```

This doesn't work, I get this error

Couldn't match type: Data.Aeson.KeyMap.KeyMap Value with: HashMap k0 v0 Expected: HashMap k0 v0
Actual: Objec In the second argument of ‘HM.lookup’, namely v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object`s used to have hashmaps in them, but don't in the most recent versions. They now contain an abstract `KeyMap` type. I don't know why they changed for sure but I wouldn't be surprised if it was to give a new type to hang class instances on. You can see more in the [documentation here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.2.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-KeyMap.html); in most cases you just need to change which module you get your operations from (i.e. your `HM.lookup` -> `Data.Aeson.KeyMap.lookup`).

Answer (score 4):

In previous versions of [aeson](/questions/tagged/aeson), this would have worked. Since `aeson-2.0.0.0` however, `aeson` no longer works with a `HashMap`, but with its own `KeyMap`, and hence you can not work with the `lookup` of a `HashMap`.

You however probably don't need to implement this manually. Indeed, you can work with lenses of the [`lens-aeson` package <sup>[hackage]</sup>](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson). You can look up a key with [**`key :: AsValue t => Key -> Traversal' t Value`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.2.3/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:key):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens.Fold ((^?))
import Data.Aeson (Value)
import Data.Aeson.Lens (key)

my_value :: Maybe Value
my_value = rep_json ^? key "names"
```

Comment: lens-aeson is also convenient to access values deeper in JSON structures, for example `rep_json ^? key "names" . nth 3 . _String` results in a `Maybe Text`